# Seconds between now and 8pm tonight in bash

Tags: bash, date, time

Lets say it's now september 20th 2015 14:43:11 and I want to know how many seconds it will be until it's today 20:00 tonight? How to do this in bash? I have been playing around with the date command.. I figured the easiest way is to calculate the current time in seconds and the 20:00 time in seconds.. however date only has a function for seconds since 1970. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I eventually found something..

```
time=20:00
now=$(date +%s)
other=$(date -d $time +%s)
diff=$((other-now))
echo $diff
```